# Toggle CAPS LOCK when you press the key

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome

HOw do I turn off the CAPS LOCK when the key is pressed?

*it's currently set to turn off on release*

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mistaken the capslock for the shift? Normally capslock should not do this. If it really does, there's a mechanical or software problem on your pc that somehow alters the state of capslock. However, shift is capslock, but only as long as the key is pressed. If its indeed the capslock, try a different keyboard to rule out a mechanical problem.

Comment: Well, Shift and Caps Lock are not the same — Caps Lock affects only letters, whereas Shift affects all keys, e.g., 1234567890=[] → !@#$%^&*()+{}.  But I agree — on my system, at least, Caps Lock takes effect (i.e., toggles / inverts the CapsLock state) as soon as I press the key down, and doesn’t wait for me to release it.

Comment: No, I had not mistaken the Caps LOck for the SHift key. I use the caps lock to capitalize letters. I am trying to solve THis:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1376903

Comment: Many users state there is a delay on Caps LOck key in LInux. Well it's not a delay, in fact the key is bind to toggle on release.  Had try a different keyboards: mac&logitech&laptop's keyboard and all waits for me to release the key. THis happens on Linux only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr, untested automated way:

```
xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY $HOME/keyboardKeys
sed -iE 's/^key <CAPS> \{[^\n]+/key <CAPS> {     repeat=no,     type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",     symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ],     actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock), Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3) ]   };/' "$HOME/keyboardKeys"

xkbcomp $HOME/keyboardKeys $DISPLAY

echo 'xkbcomp $HOME/keyboardKeys $DISPLAY' >> .profile
```

Otherwise, read on.

See if this helps:

Open the terminal and execute:

`xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY $HOME/keyboardKeys`

This will export the current keyboard settings.

Then open the text file, search for a line with:
`key <CAPS> {`
Replace it with:
`key <CAPS> {     repeat=no,     type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",     symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ],     actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock), Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3) ]   };`

Save and close the file.

Now, to temporarily apply that change run this command:

`xkbcomp $HOME/keyboardKeys $DISPLAY`

---

I don't know any way to apply this permanently but you may reapply this file change very time your session starts. For that, you can, for example, add that command to the `.profile` file in your `$HOME` directory, for example, like so:

`echo 'xkbcomp $HOME/keyboardKeys $DISPLAY' >> .profile`

Source: https://www.cuevadeclasicos.org/comunidad/temas/delay-block-mayus-en-ubuntu.16331/#post-315231